# Compile single class with jaotc of Java 10

Tags: java, aop, java-10, jaotc

I would like compile a Java 10 class file with `jaotc`. While I am able to build a shared lib of an Java 10 module I am not able figure out how to compile a single class. The FQCN of my class is `net.sweblog.jm18.aot.hw.HelloWorld` and its full path is `target/classes/net/sweblog/jm18/aot/hw/HelloWorld.class`.

So tried to invoke `jaotc` as follows:

```
$ jaotc --output output/helloworld.so \
    --search-path helloworld/target/classes/ \
    --class-name net.sweblog.jm18.aot.hw.HelloWorld

Error: Failed to find class file: net.sweblog.jm18.aot.hw.HelloWorld
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.aot/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:135)
    at jdk.aot/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:101)
    at jdk.aot/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.main(Main.java:80)
```

Does anyone know how to invoke `jaotc` correctly to compile my class file?

Comment: Are you sure you should be delimiting the commands using \? Couldn't find any documentation on that.

Comment: "\" can be used in shell scripts or on the command line to ignore line breaks. You can try on you shell.

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` could be thrown when there are no classes found by the tool to compile in the specified `searchPath` or the `files`(if specified in the `--jar` arg).

If you look at the code at [Line#135](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/jdk.aot/share/classes/jdk.tools.jaotc/src/jdk/tools/jaotc/Main.java#l135) does a

```
printer.printInfo(classesToCompile.size() + " classes found");
```

where NPE could be thrown if `classesToCompile` is null which is the case only when the lookup for classes fails in the specified path

```
try {
    foundClasses = lookup.search(this.main.options.files, this.main.options.searchPath);
} catch (InternalError var7) {
    this.main.printer.reportError(var7);
    return null;
}
```

Hence, I would recommend verifying the search path that you've specified. 
I also doubt specifying the class name `net.sweblog.jm18.aot.hw.HelloWorld` to a compiler, if I am not wrong to draw an analogy with `javac` here, it would have required a complete path for either the compiled or source class.

Comment: Disclaimer - This just went too long to be a comment, hence moved in here. Let me know if this doesn't help, would delete it.

Comment: I tried all possible variants but the problem remains.

Comment: I figured out how to invoke jaotc correctly:
cd helloworld/target/classes; jaotc --output xyz.so --search-path . --class-name net.sweblog.jm18.aot.hw.HelloWorld
So the correct usage of --search-path is not clear.